# Responsive Centered Image: Vertical Resizing - NOT

Tags: css, image

I thought I had sorted out how to do it, but I guess I still have not managed it. I am trying to achieve this with the minimum of css.

The image is centered and if you resize the window horizontally or diagonally (with an emphasis on horizontal) everything is good.

BUT if you just resize vertically, the image size stays at its nominal height and adds scroll bars.

I have tried various combinations of max-height, max-width, height and width, but none seem to have solved it.

My images will be various sizes between widths of max 1024px and heights max 768px;

My effort can be seen at

http://mclportal.net/AtLast/DeadCentre.html

```css
        #lightbox{
          background: lightblue;
          padding: 0px;
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%; 
        }
        
        #slide{
          background: #ffdb4c;
          /* height: 300px; */
          position: relative;
          top: 50%;
          
          -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          -moz-transform:    translateY(-50%);
          -ms-transform:     translateY(-50%);
          -o-transform:      translateY(-50%);
          transform:         translateY(-50%);
        }
                
        img {
            max-width: 800px;
            max-height: 600px;

            display: block;
            margin: auto;
        }

Markup:
```

```html
    
    <body>
    <div id="lightbox">
      <div id="slide">    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/" id="myImg"/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am testing with a MAC Mountain Lion and latest Firefox and Chrome

Just tested with SAFARI and it is not responsive in any direction !!

Comment: `#slide` needs `height: 100%` and `img` needs `max-height: 100%`

Comment: Now the resizing only works vertically not horizontally and the vertical centre has gone.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part with these scenarios is that your maximum width and height has to be dynamic, in the sense that they can readily adapt to different viewport orientations. If crossbrowser compatibility is not a major concern, you can use `vmax` and `vmin` units respectively for your image maximum dimension measurements, so to force the image to obey the viewport boundaries regardless of viewport orientation.

This trick only works if:

- Browser support for viewport units are available — you might have to consider fallbacks for those who don't
- That the `#lightbox` container has dimensions (both vertical and horizontal) relative to the viewport size.

```css
#lightbox{
    background: lightblue;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
}

#slide{
    background: #ffdb4c;
    /* height: 300px; */
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform:    translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform:     translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform:      translateY(-50%);
    transform:         translateY(-50%);
}

img {
    max-width: 80vmax;
    max-height: 80vmin;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="lightbox">
    <div id="slide"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/" id="myImg"/></div>
</div>
```